# Loop through ansible_play_batch repeats output

Tags: ansible

I am trying to loop through `ansible_play_batch` and get the server build date information from a csv server inventory file using the `inventory_hostname`. The problem is that it assigns the same date to all the servers and repeats the loop again to display the next server build date.
Any suggestion on how to fix to show the correct information once.

Thank you

#### Server Inventory

```
serverA,,,,2019-04-24 19:57:34
serverB,,,,2019-04-26 19:47:01
serverC,,,,2020-08-20 23:30:25
```

#### Hosts

```
serverA
serverB
serverC
```

#### Task

```yaml
- name: List Server in current play
  debug:
    msg: "Item is {{ item }} Build date {{ lookup('csvfile', item + ' file=serverInventory.csv delimiter=, col=5') }}"
  loop: "{{ ansible_play_batch }}"
```

#### Run

```
[serverMain]# ansible-playbook -i hosts_svrbuild  site.yml 

PLAY [Set_Up] ************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ***************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [serverA]
ok: [serverB]
ok: [serverC]

TASK [common : List Server in current play] ******************************************************************************************************************
ok: [serverA] => (item=serverA) => {
    "msg": "Item is serverA Build date 2019-04-24 19:57:34"
}
ok: [serverB] => (item=serverA) => {
    "msg": "Item is serverA Build date 2019-04-24 19:57:34"
}
ok: [serverC] => (item=serverA) => {
    "msg": "Item is serverA Build date 2019-04-24 19:57:34"
}
ok: [serverB] => (item=serverB) => {
    "msg": "Item is serverB Build date 2019-04-26 19:47:01"
}
ok: [serverA] => (item=serverB) => {
    "msg": "Item is serverB Build date 2019-04-26 19:47:01"
}
ok: [serverC] => (item=serverB) => {
    "msg": "Item is serverB Build date 2019-04-26 19:47:01"
}
ok: [serverB] => (item=serverC) => {
    "msg": "Item is serverC Build date 2020-08-20 23:30:25"
}
ok: [serverA] => (item=serverC) => {
    "msg": "Item is serverC Build date 2020-08-20 23:30:25"
}
ok: [serverC] => (item=serverC) => {
    "msg": "Item is serverC Build date 2020-08-20 23:30:25"
}

PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************************************************************************************************
serverA             : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
serverC             : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
serverB             : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to loop here in your task as you already have the natural play loop:

```yaml
- name: List Server in current play
  debug:
    msg: "Current server is {{ inventory_hostname }} Build date {{ lookup('csvfile', inventory_hostname + ' file=serverInventory.csv delimiter=, col=5') }}"
```

Answer (score 1):

For example,

```yaml
- hosts: serverA,serverB,serverC
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "Item is {{ item }}
              Build date {{ lookup('csvfile',
                                   item,
                                   file='serverInventory.csv',
                                   delimiter=',',
                                   col=4) }}"
      loop: "{{ ansible_play_batch }}"
      run_once: true
```

gives

```yaml
PLAY [serverA,serverB,serverC] ***************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [serverA] => (item=serverA) => 
  msg: Item is serverA Build date 2019-04-24 19:57:34
ok: [serverA] => (item=serverB) => 
  msg: Item is serverB Build date 2019-04-26 19:47:01
ok: [serverA] => (item=serverC) => 
  msg: Item is serverC Build date 2020-08-20 23:30:25

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
serverA: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

Without the iteration, the task below

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "Item is {{ inventory_hostname }}
              Build date {{ lookup('csvfile',
                                   inventory_hostname,
                                   file='serverInventory.csv',
                                   delimiter=',',
                                   col=4) }}"
```

gives the same messages

```yaml
TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [serverA] => 
  msg: Item is serverA Build date 2019-04-24 19:57:34
ok: [serverB] => 
  msg: Item is serverB Build date 2019-04-26 19:47:01
ok: [serverC] => 
  msg: Item is serverC Build date 2020-08-20 23:30:25
```

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest leveraging Python split function instead of the csv plugin:

**Code:**

```
  - name: List Server in current play
    debug:
      msg: "Item is {{ item.split(',')[0] }} Build date: {{ item.split(',')[-1] }}"
    with_lines: cat servers.csv
```

**Explanation:**

Iterating over the file one line at a time. The Python *split* function using comma to split a line into a list of tokens. The first token(accessed with index of 0) is the server name, the last token (and I assume date is the last field in your file that contains no commas) is addressed with index of -1

**Output:**

```
TASK [List Server in current play] *********************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=serverA,,,,2019-04-24 19:57:34) => {
    "msg": "Item is serverA Build date: 2019-04-24 19:57:34"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=serverB,,,,2019-04-26 19:47:01) => {
    "msg": "Item is serverB Build date: 2019-04-26 19:47:01"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=serverC,,,,2020-08-20 23:30:25) => {
    "msg": "Item is serverC Build date: 2020-08-20 23:30:25"
}
```

Comment: This will return all lines inside the file and possibly some which are not in the current play loop. Morevove, this will not fix the fact the result is displayed several time as the file file will be looped over once for each server in the play. If the above was actually meeting OP's requirment, it should display nothing as you are running against localhost only which is not part of the csv file.